# Best way of doing API to Salesforce authentication?

Tags: oauth2, authentication

I am integrating an API with Salesforce. The maintainer of Salesforce has given us access via the Username / Password flow. I can successfully get an access_token and work with the custom apexrest endpoint. On a trial account I also made the JWT bearer server-server flow work.

Obviously the access_token expires at some point. But there is no expiry returned with the access token, only an issued_at. Theoretically if I knew what the life-time of the access token was, I could refresh it before it expires. But in practice, Salesforce returns the same access token as long as it is valid, so I can't refresh it before it expires.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any way to have a permanent or very long-termed token
   (because the two integrating parties have a high level of trust
   between us)
2. Is there any way to make Salesforce issue a fresh token every time we authenticate?
3. What is the best way to handle Oauth flow between an API and Salesforce in general?
4. Is there any flows that give me an expiry on the access token?
5. Is it possible to avoid having to do an error-fallback flow: When I get a 401 I reauthenticate and repeat the original request?

There can be any number of instances running this API, and there might be a lot of incoming requests while re-authorizations is carried out, so we want to avoid any race-condition scenario.

Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: This really needs splitting into a number of questions as the format is meant to be a specific question, e.g. 'Are there any flows that give me an expiry on the access token using API integration?'. As this currently stands it is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't getting an expiry because there isn't really a set time that an access token will expire. Each time you make a request, the session tied to the access token has its timeout refreshed.

As long as you make a request before the session timeout (which can be controlled either by the org-wide security settings (by default), or by setting session timeout in the connected app you created/installed), the access token will never expire unless you revoke it through the Salesforce UI.

Because of that, the best (read: only) approach for handling expired tokens is to detect when it happens (on the client end), then go through the process of getting a new token, and finally retry your request. It'd be a good thing to add to your solution (though with the volume of requests you're implying, it'll probably never be used).

For requests that don't involve a human (e.g. server to server), the JWT flow is the way to go.

Comment: What is the longest session-timeout possible? Is that 24 hours?

Comment: @Luhmann Yep, 24 hours. Though, again, that timeout is reset each time you make a request. I personally have an integration that's effectively been using the same access token for a year (the last time we updated the cert used).

Comment: Thank you for your replies, it has been very helpful.